# Adding Log4Net to Unity

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio

I would like to add `log4net` library as a logging tool to visual studio project which created by `Unity`, Is this possible?

I dragged the `log4net` DLL to assembly references in `Visual Studio`. so the DLL added to the project, but when I want to import it in code with `using log4net`, it doesn't find the library!

Comment: I tried to add log4net dll as an assembly to project, but I didnt know how exacly to do that, so I just drag the dll to the References. But when I added `using log4net;`, it doesnt find it!

Comment: Yes, You're right :) I'm just a bit lazy. I found how to fix this, I should be placed the library in unity asset folder or plugin folder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I found the solution, So it's absolutely possible to use `log4net` or any other managed library with `Unity`. But I made a mistake, I should be followed the [Unity manual page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html) which said:

> Usually, scripts are kept in a project as source files and compiled by
>   Unity whenever the source changes. However, it is also possible to
>   compile a script to a dynamically linked library (DLL) using an
>   external compiler. The resulting DLL can then be added to the project
>   and the classes it contains can be attached to objects just like
>   normal scripts.
>   **the DLL file can simply be dragged into the Unity project like any other asset.**

So I just needed to add the `log4net` DLL to asset folder and it would be accessible through `Visual Studio`.